# Drawing knot on Latex

Tags: diagrams, draw, tikz-graphdrawing, tikz-knots

I want to draw some knots for my master's dissertation, but I dont want to do that by including pictures of them. Can I do this on latex? If this is possible how? If not, are there any apps which can help me with it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I must admit that I do not have a clue, what kind of knot you need. Please show an example (link, picture) and ideally also what you have achieved so far (a minimal working example).

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:tikz-knots]. Have you had a look at the [tag description](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/tikz-knots/info)? Probably not. Do so and follow the path down the rabbit hole...

Comment: You can take a look at the `pst-knot` package.

Comment: @Jürgen I would like to draw pretzel links. You can find an example here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretzel_link

Comment: @Soukaina Hamri This should be possible using the `tikz-knots` library (I didn't know it up to now). Please look into the manual and give it a try. If you run into problems come back and show us your mwe. You will be welcome!